# Check if the binary of a number has equal no of 0's and 1's

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

We are given a integer number, and the task is to tell whether the binary representation of the number includes equal number of binary `1`'s and `0`'s or not?
I want the solution in constant time.
I have the code for calculating no of 1s with the help of hamming weight algorithm!
Please help i want to count no of `0`'s!!

Comment: Is "the binary of the number" a fixed number of bits, or a variable number of bits? For example, would the answer be "yes" for input 2? Both `10` and `00000010` are common ways of writing the number in binary.

Comment: I'd like to point out [bitwise operators in C and C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).  This is probably the approach your professor is looking for.

Comment: its not a homework. i was practising a programming problem and got stuck here. i did the brute force approach by dividing a number by 2 and checking for even and odd. but this gave me TLE. so asked fr the help

Comment: If it's not a homework, check my answer on using `std::bitset` in C++

Comment: @user3185786 Nikos is right! His answer gives you a much more efficient solution than calling the `ceil(log2(x))` functions.

Comment: if you can count the 1s, can't you subtract it from the total number of bits to get the 0's? This is trivial and don't worth a question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x - is your number, N1 is the number of "1" then

```
int N0 = ceil(log2(x)) - N1;
```

will calculate number of "0". Do not forget

```
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: Sure about `<math.h>`, shouldn't this be `<cmath>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not if you want `::ceil` and `::log2` that this answer is using. `<cmath>` is for `std::ceil` and `std::log2`.

Comment: @hvd Since the question's tagged [tag:c++] ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Both `<math.h>` and `<cmath>` are available in all conforming C++ implementations, with slightly different requirements about the declared functions.

Comment: The fastest way is to use the intrinsic function _popcnt (32 bit integer) or _popcnt64(64 bit integer), which translates into a single X86 instruction on modern X86 cpus. It returns the number of 1 bits. The next fastest way is to clear the least significant 1 bit, 1 at a time using x &= x-1;

Comment: This is the worst answer here. The OP already used Hamming weight to count bits which may be tens or hundreds of times faster

Answer (score 2):

In production code (I mean if not restricted by rules dictated in an assignment) I'd do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    int k(24); // an example integer - the one you check for equality of 0's and ones
    std::bitset<32> bs(k); // I suppose 32 bit numbers - choose your own length

    if ( 16 == bs.count() ) // 16 is half the bit length - count returns the bits that are swithced ON
    {
        std::cout << "Equal number of 1s and 0s\n";
    }
}
```

I mean after all the question is tagged c++

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfZeros = numberOfBinaryDigits - numberOfOnes;
```

Where number of binary digits is either based on the storage used for the data, or log2.

Comment: It's not really clear from the question which answer it wants.  Would 2 be have an equal number or not?

Answer (score 0):

32 bit integer examples:

Using bit operators (and multiply):

```
int bitcount(unsigned int i)
{
    // generate a bit count in each pair of bits
    i = i - ( (i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    // generate a bit count in each nibble
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ( (i >> 2) & 0x33333333 );
    // sum up the bits counts in the nibbles
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

Using gcc popcount:

```
int bitcount(unsigned int i)
{
    return(__builtin_popcount(i));
}
```

using visual studio popcnt:

```
int bitcount(unsigned int i)
{
    return(_popcnt(i));
}
```

//  if(16 == bitcount(i)), then equal number of 1's and 0's.